# How do i get country boundary and names to show up in postgis backed mapnik rendered map?

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles

I followed [this](http://www.hyperionreactor.net/blog/how-build-your-own-osm-server-part-1-postgis-and-mapnik) to setup postgis server with planet-latest.osm. I used [generate_xml.py](http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/rendering/mapnik) to generate stylesheets. Using this style sheet with mapnik produces a world map with no country boundaries or country name on it. What is the best way to render tiles that looks similar to official tiles.openstreetmap.org tiles.

For example, for same zoom, x, y, this is what i get:

[image]

And this is what tile.openstreetmap.org has:

[image]

Comment: do you have the world boundaries and coastline? http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/rendering/mapnik/openstreetmap-mapnik-world-boundaries/debian/update_world_boundaries_dir.sh

Comment: @Mapperz, I just now fixed the issue. I did not have proj-epsg package installed. Installing it solve the problem.

Comment: @Mapperz, Just did. However if someone can explain what proj-epsg provides and why installing that fixed the problem, I'll accept that as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had `proj-epsg` package missing. Installing this package fixed the problem.